# Regex: Split characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Example two String

> 9:00 AM Wake up
>   1:00 PM Lunch Time

Separate using **AM** or **PM** 

Desire output:

> 9:00, AM, Wake up
> 1:00, PM, LunchT ime

What regex should I use to separate the time and string to and keep the separator as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\s*([AP]M)\s*/
```

By enclosing the split regex in parentheses, its match is added to the resulting array. The `\s*` (outside the group) match the surrounding whitespace, if present, thus removing them from the match.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the case always, make it simple. Just split it using a space(`' '`) and take the first 2 string array values. Ignore rest of the space in between.

For Example:

```
9:00 AM Wake up
```

Here, 
After splitting there will be 4 strings in the split array`{"9:00","AM","Wake","up"}`
take first 2 elements and and append the rest of the elements with a space.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "9:00 AM Wake up";
        input = input.replaceFirst("\\s+","\\,").replaceFirst("\\s+","\\,");
        System.out.println(input);
        
        input = "1:00 PM Lunch Time";
        input = input.replaceFirst("\\s+","\\,").replaceFirst("\\s+","\\,");
        System.out.println(input);
    }
```

After running above code output would be.

> 9:00,AM,Wake up
>
> 1:00,PM,Lunch Time